# linkedList remove_all function

Tags: c++

I'm writing list and iterator classes function and I'm almost done, but I get some errors in the main file, that when I write the list remove_all function, but when I delete it there is no error anywhere, I don't know why!! Also, actually I'm not sure about my Iterator operators and the `bool Iterator::is_item()`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

here is my codes:

Node.h

```
pragma once

namespace list_1
{
    template <typename T>
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node<T> *next;


        // Constructor
        // Postcondition: 
        Node<T> (T d);
    };

    template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T d)
{

}
}
```

Iterator.h

```
// Template CLASS PROVIDED: Iterator 

#pragma once
#include "Node.h"

namespace list_1
{
    template<typename T>
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        Iterator<T> (Node<T> *np);
        // precondition: is_item is true
        // post condition n points to the next item in the list
        void operator++();
        // precondition: 
        // postcondition: returns true if there is a valid item
        bool is_item();
        // precondition: is_item == true
        // postcondition returns data that n is pointing at
        T operator* ();

    private:
        Node<T>* n;

    };
```

List.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include "Node.h"
#include "Iterator.h"

namespace list_1
{
    template <typename T>
    class list
    {
    public:
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        list( );
        // postcondition: all nodes in the list are destroyed.
        ~list();
        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        //postcondition: entry is added to the front of the list
        void insert_front(const T& entry);
        //postcondition: entry is added to the back of the list
        void add_back(const T& entry);
        // postcondition: all nodes with data == entry are removed from the list
        void remove_all(const T& entry);
        // postcondition: an iterator is created pointing to the head of the list
        Iterator<T> begin(void);

        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        // postcondition: the size of the list is returned
        int size( ) const;
    private:
        Node<T>* head;

    };
```

Comment: Some errors? What kind of errors?

Comment: syntax errors, while everything is right in the main!!

Comment: It would help to know what kind of syntax errors. (Actually, I suspect they have something to do with the call to `cout` without including `<iostream>` or namespace qualifying it...)

Comment: end of file was left before the left brac .... was matched. Also, expected a declaration, like those errors. Actually, I included the <iostream> but still not fixed!

Comment: Check my answer below, you were missing 2 closing braces.

Comment: Thanks Arthur,, that was fixed

Comment: but I still have problem with the Iterator::is_item and list::size,, could you check them guys.. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax errors are because you are missing a couple closing curly brackets on your "else" blocks at the end of the remove_all function.

Try replacing it with this

(edit: included the suggestion about cout mentioned in the comments above)

```
void list<T>::remove_all(const T& entry)
{
    if(head == 0)
    {
        std::cout<<" node cannot be delted";

    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> *curr = head;
        Node<T> *trail = 0;

        while( curr != 0)
        {
            if(curr->entry == entry)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                trail = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
            if(curr == 0)
            {
                std::cout<<" Node " << entry<< " is not found";
            }
            else
            {
                if ( head == curr)
                {
                    head = head->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    trail->next = curr->next;
                }
            } // missing this one
     delete curr;
     } // and this one as well
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but also the iterator:: is_item has a problem if you know how it should be fixed!

Comment: becuase when I call it in the main.cpp in show_list function,, it does'nt work when I compile!

Comment: you did not provide your main.cpp, so I can't see this show_list function. Edit your question to include that code

Comment: I've edited it and provide that function. I think I did is_item in how it should be but I'm not sure why is not working. I also tried with turning true and false but is the same!

Comment: @Mido the problem is that 1) is_item does not check whether n is null, it should be `return (n != NULL && n->data != NULL);` and also 2) you actually make your nodes invalid when you delete them on `list::insert_front`. You're basically telling `head` to point to a position and then you delete what is in that position, making it invalid. Remove the `delete new_node;` inside `list::insert_front` and change the `is_item` as above and see if it helps.